# SPD 2010 List workflow not resolving email addresses

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, workflow, email

I've got a list workflow that sends out an email to a user based on a workflow lookup for the current list item. I've set it up to send the email to the email address of the user named in the "Waiting On" field.

When I use myself in the "Waiting On" column, the email is generated and sent properly. However, if any other user is named in the field, the email is addressed to their UserID Number.

Instead of showing up addressed to first.last@company.com, it appears addressed to: 9

Any clues?

Comment: What exact field are you using for the email recipient in SP Designer?

Comment: The field name is "Waiting On". -its type is Person or Group. The field's settings are show=Name; allow selection of=People Only; Choose from=All Users; Allow blank values=true; Allow multiple values=false